# Issues with output while connecting using nodejs mssql

Tags: sql, node.js, intersystems-cache

I'm new to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and I'm trying to connect to a [intersystems-cache](/questions/tagged/intersystems-cache) database.  Here is what I have, based off the sample code in the docs:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

console.log("Connecting...");

sql.connect("mssql://username:password@server:1234/DB").then(function(){
    console.log("connected");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

If I put in the wrong server or port, I get a `Failed to connect` error, but no matter what else I enter incorrectly (username, pass, db) I get zero output.  More importantly, when all the data is correct I never get the `connected` output.

Is this a compatibility issue with Cache and the `mssql` library?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you use mssql, instead of cache, while you have to connect to cache.
If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJS_methods#BXJS_methods_open), you may find and example

```
var globals = require('cache');
var mydata = new globals.Cache();
mydata.open(
  { path:"/cache20102/mgr",
    username: "_SYSTEM",
    password: "SYS",
    namespace: "USER"
  },
  function(error, result){}
);
```

Comment: Found this doc: http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJS_intro

Pointed me to a downloads page... working on it.

Comment: cache0100.node and cache0120.node you may find in instance's bin directory, which you should rename to cache.nod. Where 0100 and 0120 means node's version 0.10 and 0.12

Comment: Umm, `node -v`  `v4.4.7`

Comment: I guess I'll just go back to VBScript and SQL